# Разбиение массива на n равных частей

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, есть такая проблема:
Есть массив размера m, как разбить его на n равных частей(если это невозможно, то последний массив содержит "лишние" элементы). Нужно получить индексы начала и конца подмассивов(если можно так выразиться).
Желательно код на java, но и просто словами с радостью бы почитал.

Comment: У вас массив из 13 элементов. Расскажите как разбить его на N (N > 1) равных частей, можно словами.

Comment: n = 2: 6 и 7; n = 3: 4 4 5; n = 4: 3 3 3 4 и т.д.

Comment: А где равные части-то? 6 никак не равно 7...

Comment: Все равные части, кроме последней, да, так правильнее.

Comment: Тогда разделение на 2n или 2n+1 частей - то что вам нужно. Школьная математика.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всякое четное число может быть записано в виде 2n, а всякое нечетное в виде 2n+1. Соответственно, задача сводится к определению четности, нахождению n и поиску индексов начала и конца "подмассивов".

Comment: Думаю, я как-то неправильно понял, но разве это не деление массива на 2 части?

Comment: 13 = 2n+1, найдите n.

Comment: Спасибо, я вас понял